# How to group by consecutive rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, row, grouping

Following example lines of some data I have:

```
A   B    participant   trial   CURRENT_ID      C
0   1    ppt01         45      3               0   #row1
1   0    ppt01         45      4               0   #row2
0   1    ppt01         45      10              0   #row3
0   0    ppt01         45      11              0   #row4
1   0    ppt01         45      12              0   #row5
0   1    ppt01         87      2               0   #row6
1   0    ppt01         87      3               0   #row7
1   1    ppt01         87      4               1   #row8
1   1    ppt01         87      5               1   #row9
0   1    ppt02         55      5               0   #row10
1   0    ppt02         55      6               0   #row11
0   1    ppt02         55      9               0   #row12
1   0    ppt02         55      10              0   #row13
0   1    ppt02         55      11              1   #row14
1   0    ppt02         55      12              0   #row15
```

I need to group the data by participant, trial and consecutive rows of CURRENT_ID. However, the consecutive rows of CURRENT_ID need to be considered by participant and trial, and may need to be considered twice. Here an example of how I need to consider the consecutive rows. As you can see, some of the rows need to be considered twice (e.g., participant ppt01, trial 45, CURRENT_ID 11), with the previous and following row:

```
A   B    participant   trial   CURRENT_ID      C
0   1    ppt01         45      3               0   #row1
1   0    ppt01         45      4               0   #row2

0   1    ppt01         45      10              0   #row3
0   0    ppt01         45      11              0   #row4

0   0    ppt01         45      11              0   #row4
1   0    ppt01         45      12              0   #row5

0   1    ppt01         87      2               0   #row6
1   0    ppt01         87      3               0   #row7

1   0    ppt01         87      3               0   #row7
1   1    ppt01         87      4               1   #row8

1   1    ppt01         87      4               1   #row8
1   1    ppt01         87      5               1   #row9

0   1    ppt02         55      5               0   #row10
1   0    ppt02         55      6               0   #row11

0   1    ppt02         55      9               0   #row12
1   0    ppt02         55      10              0   #row13

1   0    ppt02         55      10              0   #row13
0   1    ppt02         55      11              1   #row14

0   1    ppt02         55      11              1   #row14
1   0    ppt02         55      12              0   #row15
```

How to include the consecutive rows of CURRENT_ID in `library(dplyr)` `group_by(participant,trial)`?

Comment: How do you want to reorganize the data?

Comment: Wjy are A, B, C, and the # comments there? Why is specifically 11 doubled?

Comment: I would like to group_by the data because then I need to do some calculations with the columns A, B, and C based on the grouping by participant, trial and consecutive rows of CURRENT_ID.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to do it with `dplyr`, but here is an approach in base R:

```
# data
dat <- structure(list(A = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), participant = c("ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", 
"ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt01", "ppt02", 
"ppt02", "ppt02", "ppt02", "ppt02", "ppt02"), trial = c(45L, 
45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 
55L), CURRENT_ID = c(3L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "participant", 
"trial", "CURRENT_ID", "C"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")

# where can the consecutives start? Only look at those with same trial/participant
idx <- which(diff(dat[,"CURRENT_ID"])==1)
idx <- Filter(function(i) dat[i,"trial"]==dat[i+1,"trial"], idx)
idx <- Filter(function(i) dat[i,"participant"]==dat[i+1,"participant"], idx)

# create the dataframes
lapply(idx, function(i) dat[c(i,i+1),])
```